# Hide a menu for 30 seconds in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hide a menu for 30 seconds in angularjs and this is my attempt

```
.controller('MenuTimingController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
       $timeout(function () { $scope.loadAlertMessage = true; }, 30000);   
});
```

This is in the index file

```
<div ng-controller="MenuTimingController"> 
                  <div ng-model="loadAlertMessage">
                <a menu-close ng-click="gotoMainPage()" style="color:black" ui-sref="entry" class="item"><i class="icon ion-android-contact"> Main Menu</i> </a></div></div>
```

But my challenge is that the menu is never hidden. Please where am I wrong.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would cause it to ever be hidden?

Comment: you need `ng-show`/`ng-hide` or '`ng-if` instead of  `ng-model="loadAlertMessage"`

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. changed it to ng-if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-show or ng-hide to control the html element's visibility; and also , use the DOT magic.

```
.controller('MenuTimingController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
   // init the $scope.show.loadAlertMessage
   $scope.show = {loadAlertMessage : false};
   $timeout(function () { $scope.show.loadAlertMessage = true; }, 30000);   
  });

  // the html code
  <div ng-show="show.loadAlertMessage">
```